# how can you save an xml api query?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer  9d4e1ef8b563b40f9a8737768a18e64d'}
data = requests.get('https://api.deutschebahn.com/timetables/v1/fchg/8005598', headers=header)
print(data.status_code)

root = ET.Element(data.text)
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
ET.dump(tree)

tree.write("output.xml")
```

Output the Problem is that first **<** and last **/>** because of them i can´t process this in a outher python file

```
<<timetable station="Solingen Mitte" eva="8005598">

<s id="1543646512857847927-2002091043-11" eva="8005598">
    <ar ct="2002091132" l="S7">
        <m id="r62168053" t="d" c="34" ts="2002091125"/>
    </ar>
    <dp ct="2002091133" l="S7">
        <m id="r62168053" t="d" c="34" ts="2002091125"/>
    </dp>
</s>


<s id="211367266806957448-2002091122-3" eva="8005598">
    <ar ct="2002091131" l="S7"/>
    <dp ct="2002091131" l="S7"/>
</s>

<s id="1234459647772462334-2002091052-3" eva="8005598">
    <ar ct="2002091102" l="S7"/>
    <dp ct="2002091102" l="S7"/>
</s>
</timetable>
 />
```

I am unfortunately still a very experienced programmer. Thank you

Comment: where do you want to save xml, in a file or any other database

Comment: With ET.Element you’re creating an element whose name is the value of data.text. Not sure why you want to create a tree instead of writing data.text directly to a file, but maybe try ET.fromstring() instead.

Comment: Also, I’d recommend using data.content with fromstring. See https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content for more details.